# List the first 4 lines of all the files in a given directory

Tags: ls, head

What command could I create that will list the first 4 lines of all the files in a given directory?

Comment: `head -4 /some/directory/*`?

Comment: echo "Please input the location of the directory you would like to list"
        read $dirname
head -4 ~/$dirname/*
How could i implement it to this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add clarifications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[root@xxx httpd]# head -n 4 /var/log/httpd/*
==> /var/log/httpd/access_log <==
xxxx - - [06/Dec/2015:22:22:45 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.0.303.52"
xxxx - - [06/Dec/2015:22:22:46 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 291 "http://195.154.165.63:8001/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.0.303.52"

==> /var/log/httpd/access_log-20151018 <==
xxxx - - [12/Oct/2015:14:05:42 +0200] "GET /git HTTP/1.1" 404 281 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
xxxx - - [12/Oct/2015:14:05:42 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 289 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
xxxx - - [12/Oct/2015:14:05:43 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 289 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"
xxxx - - [12/Oct/2015:14:06:24 +0200] "GET /git HTTP/1.1" 502 465 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0"

==> /var/log/httpd/access_log-20151115 <==
xxxx - - [14/Nov/2015:18:56:04 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
xxxx - - [14/Nov/2015:18:56:05 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 291 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
xxxx - - [14/Nov/2015:18:56:05 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 291 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
xxxx - - [14/Nov/2015:18:58:28 +0100] "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1" 403 294 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101   Firefox/42.0"
```

It's a sample of my httpd directory with the command `head -n 4 /var/log/httpd/*` for the first 4 lines. Replace `head -n 4` by `head -n 1` for the first lines.

And you can replace the directory `/var/log/httpd/*` with your directory for example, `/my/directory/*` but don't forget the wildcard at the end (`*`).
This wildcard permits to tell that we want all the (non-hidden) files in the directory.

Comment: If you also want hidden files, you can use `find`: `find /some/path -type f -exec head -4 {} +`, this will also traverse subdirectories for you

Answer (score 3):

If you only want those 4 lines content and not the file names:

```
awk 'FNR<=4' ./*.log
```

To have the lines prefixed with the file names:

```
awk 'FNR<=4 {print FILENAME ": " $0}' ./*.log
```

Or with GNU `grep`:

```
grep -Hm4 '^' ./*.log
```

Comment: +1 for a (very) portable one (./ to avoid some pb with filenames, and awk is available on some (very) old systems where tail doesn't support more than 1 file). But gnu grep m4 is an oddity here... seems like it has a bit of "creeping-featurism" ^^ [edit: I looked into -m : it is in fact quite handy and clever, and I understand now why it's added in. Not out of context in grep at all, especially the way it handles the seeking position in the file]

Comment: an alternative way: print the filename and then the lines : `awk 'FNR==1 {printf "\n%s:\n",FILENAME } FNR<=4' ./*.log`

Answer (score 1):

If by "all files" you mean "regular files" and not directories, sockets, FIFOs, etc, then you'll need to find those using, well, `find`:

```sh
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

and pass them to `xargs` to invoke `head` on them:

```sh
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 head -n 4
```

If you also want to follow symbolic links that eventually point at regular files, then use `-xtype` in place of `-type` (or use `find -L` in place of `find`).

(I've assumed GNU `find` and `xargs` above; if you're not in GNU environment, see notes in the comments).

Comment: Note that `-maxdepth`, `-print0` and `-0` are GNU extensions (though now supported by a few other implementations). POSIXly: `find "$dir/." ! -name . -prune -type f -exec head -n 4 {} +`.

Comment: Note that `xargs` or `-exec {} +` may end up running `head` several times. If the last batch has only one file, its name will not be printed. GNU `head` has a `-v` option to work around that.

Comment: Note that contrary to `"$dir"/*`, it will include hidden files and not sort the file list.